# Eigen3 Matrix Random

Tags: c++, eigen3

i want to use the Eigen3 library with the random number generator Mersenne Twister, is there a simple way to extend eigen (simple) ?

I cannot find in the documentation of eigen what random number generator they are using and if its thread safe?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Borgleader a good and elegant way to initialise a eigen3 matrix.

Comment: Why would you care about the RNG in Eigen? C++ comes standard with the Mersenne Twister RNG(in `<random>`). Since that's OO, it's not naturally threadsafe but each thread can have its own RNG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a15f13ef961b2c0709c8904281260222f) for an example showing how to use C++11 random generators within Eigen. You can easily adapt it to use the `std::mersenne_twister_engine` engine.

Comment: For future reference: The method one has to use is `NullaryExpr`. There the documentation linked above does indeed include an example for exactly this use case. It just took me a while to find it.

Comment: Indeed, for some reason the link within the page does not work from outside.